# Arduino - How to cycle through hex colours from 000000 to FFFFFF?

Tags: c, hex, arduino, rgb

I have a project involving an LED module that uses a 3-colour LED which can be controlled by  passing in an RGB hex colour, eg `22AAFF`

How could I cycle from `000000` to `FFFFFF` if I start with this?

```
long color = 0x000000;
```

I want to have a loop that does every iteration and displays every possible colour, to end up with

```
color = 0xFFFFFF
```

I'm not sure if my understanding of the hex representation of colours makes sense!?

Comment: Do you need a hex string or an int value?

Comment: You're going to spend a long time looking at the leds. That's more than 16 million different colors.

Comment: Every possible colour form 0x000000 to 0xFFFFFF is 16777216 colours. If you look at each colour for one second, and continue to do so 8 hours a day, 5 days a week, it will take you about 27 months to see all the colours. If you are not afraid of it, you may use a loop like this: `for (color = 0; color <= 0xFFFFFF; ++color) { ... }`

Answer (score 12):

What's wrong with the obvious `for (int color = 0x000000; color <= 0xFFFFFF; ++color)` ?

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like this

```
for (int color = 0x000000; color <= 0xFFFFFF; ++color)
```

But as it was mentioned in the comments, this will take a long time to display all the 16 million colors not to mention that the leds can be unable to display all these colors, so you will probably want something like this:

```
const int step = 8; // Select this to be a power of two if you want the maximum brightness to be reachable
for( int red = 0x00; red <= 0xFF; red += step ) {
    for( int green = 0x00; green <= 0xFF; green += step ) {
        for( int blue = 0x00; blue <= 0xFF; blue += step ) {
            const int color = blue << 16 + green << 8 + red;
            // Change the led settings here.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, to reach the maximum brightness, `step` should divide 255, not 256. That means it can only be 3, 5, 17 or a product of those.

Answer (score 4):

I think you don't want to loop through All colors but through HUE channel in HSV(HSB) color model. If this is so, you may google for the implementation of the function that converts HSV value to RGB. And you code will look like this:

```
for(int hue=0; hue<360; hue++)
    setColorHSV(hue,1,1);
```

One of the possible implementations you can find [here](http://eduardofv.com/read_post/179-Arduino-RGB-LED-HSV-Color-Wheel-).

If you don't want to bother with this function you can use this dummy loops:

```
unsigned int i;
for(i = 0; i <= 0xFF; i++)
{
    rgb = 0xFF0000 | i<<8;  
    setLed(rgb);
}
while(--i > 0)
{
    rgb = 0x00FF00 | i<<16; 
    setLed(rgb);
}
for(i = 0; i <= 0xFF; i++)
{
    rgb = 0x00FF00 | i; 
    setLed(rgb);
}
while(--i > 0)
{
    rgb = 0x0000FF | i<<8;  
    setLed(rgb);
}
for(i = 0; i <= 0xFF; i++)
{
    rgb = 0x0000FF | i<<16; 
    setLed(rgb);
}
while(--i > 0)
{
    rgb = 0xFF0000 | i;
    setLed(rgb);
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't test it, but I think it should work without problems. And of course you can optimize it as you want.

Comment: +1, but `unsigned int i` is always `>=0` so there're a few infinite cycles in your code...

Comment: wasn't changing the type if `i` more simple and more readable than this? And this never gets called with `i == 0`, which is kind of not what you wanted?

Comment: I don't need `i == 0` and `i == 0xFF` in `while`-loops. They appear in the  following and preceding `for`-loops respectively.